# PHP - Progress bar with JS for long-loading script

Tags: javascript, php, html

today i have to use Progress bar for my PHP Script.

Its my php script with js progress bar.

```
<?php 

$counter = 100;
for($i = 1; $i<=$counter; $i++)
{
    $percent = intval($i/$counter * 100);

                echo '<script language="javascript">
    document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML="<div style=\"width:'.$percent.';background-color:#ddd;\">&nbsp;</div>";
    document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="'.$i.' row(s) processed.";
    </script>';
}
?>
```

and html file:

```
<div id="progress" style="width:auto;border:1px solid #ccc;"></div>
<div id="information" style="width"></div>
```

Everything would be great but when i look at my source code of site there are for example:

$counter = 100; = ~300 line's in source-code

$counter = 200; = ~600 line's in source-code

$counter = 500; = ~1500 line's in source-code

Comment: Are you really inserting that script 100 times in the page?

Comment: XD. you cannot do that this way, you need to use ajax if you want to display a progressbar/a spinner while loading something...

Comment: no, i add '100' only for example

Comment: so yeah, you are inserting that script 100 times...

Comment: i dont think so but what about source-code ? affects the quality?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not the right language to put a progress bar on.  PHP executes everything at once, then it sends its data to the client in one go.

Most you can do, is detect the "ready state", this gives you 4 or 5 values for your progress bar.

And of course you can fake it.  Pretend the progress bar is responding to the server, while it's just some timer

Now, what you could do, is make multiple AJAX requests, each of these requests triggers php to process 300 lines.  But I'm not sure if a progress bar is worth the trouble of doing this.